# Call method String java from ndk with languge c++

Tags: java-native-interface

i want to call method inside java and retrun a string to ndk but my app will crash when i calling java method . 
i checked more stackoverflow site  but when im using other codes,it dont work.
help me thanks

inside ndk code :

```
extern "C"
 JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
 Java_com_hppni_battleword_view_SplashScreen_tkk(JNIEnv *env, jclass type) {
 jclass jClass = env->FindClass("com/hppni/battleword/view/SplashScreen");
 if (jClass != nullptr) {
    jmethodID mid2 = env->GetStaticMethodID(jClass, "encryptThisString",
                                            "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"); // app will crash here
    if (mid2 != nullptr) {
        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jClass, mid2, (jstring) "ali"); // app will crash here
    }
}
 return env->NewStringUTF(getSignature(env));
}
```

inside java class/Activity :

```
 public static String encryptThisString(String input) {
    Log.d("NDK", input);
  return input;
 }
```

Comment: You must call `CallStaticObjectMethod` instead, as `encryptThisString` clearly returns a `java.lang.String` object. You should also do something with the `jobject` that it will return.

Comment: @Botje i changed to method CallStaticObjectMethod  
but still crash ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just cast `char *` string to `jstring`. You need to create `jstring` object using JNI functions like `NewStringUTF`, for example.

Comment: i changed but still crashing .
can you check jmethodID mid2 = env->GetStaticMethodID(jClass, "encryptThisString",
                                            "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");

Comment: `env->CallStaticObjectMethod(jClass, mid2, env->NewStringUTF("ali"))` instead of what you have now. And don't forget to do something with the result!

Comment: @Botje if i want it :
std::string result =env->CallStaticObjectMethod(jClass, mid2, env->NewStringUTF("ali")) ;
how can i write this code ?
im learing ndk thanks

Comment: That is a new question, but see [the JNI Cookbook](http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-009/) to get a `char *` and construct an `std::string` from there.